# WebRTC H.264 support on Android

Tags: android, webrtc, h.264

I know there has been written a lot about it, and from what I read, H.264 should be supported if it's Qualcomm device with h264 hardware encoder.

I'm pretty sure my Nexus 5X qualifies for it, and logs confirms it:

```
I/org.webrtc.Logging: MediaCodecVideoEncoder: Found target encoder for mime video/avc : OMX.qcom.video.encoder.avc. Color: 0x15. Bitrate adjustment: NO_ADJUSTMENT
```

But it doesn't show up in SDP:

```
m=video 9 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 96 98 100 127 97 99 101
a=rtpmap:96 VP8/90000
a=rtpmap:98 VP9/90000
a=rtpmap:100 red/90000
a=rtpmap:127 ulpfec/90000
a=rtpmap:97 rtx/90000
a=rtpmap:99 rtx/90000
a=rtpmap:101 rtx/90000
```

Any idea why is that and how can I fix it? Politics/licensing? Should I eneable some flag during build or something?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the default WebView in Android, which is based on Chromium, there won't be H.264 support, both decode and encode, as Chromium does not build with ffmpeg by default.

Chrome, however, does have support for H.264.

So one route you can venture would be building your own Chromium WebView with the ffmpeg flags enabled and bundle it with you apk.

Comment: I'm using native (C + Java) WebRTC SDK, so that won't help.